Is it possible to restrict the size of commits (diff) directly to master in Bitbucket?
The title says it all.
I know you can forbid commits/pushes to master completely but for pragmatic reasons I still want to allow my team to make "small" changes there (a few dozen lines per commit max or so). Is there a feature for this in bitbucket?
Looking around the bitbucket options I saw nothing right away.

I don't use bitbucket, but look into the available hooks.  You'll have to write the script yourself, but it'd probably work.

why are you restricting them and what are the requirements for each commit?

I don't use bitbucket, but if CI workflows are allowed and can be required pass on PRs, you could enforce your rules in such a workflow and require PRs to push to master.

(Opinion) Seems like setting a specific limit will be problematic. Some one char change could break everything. And you're bound to periodically have "small" changes just a few chars over your limit. Sounds impractical.

Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server? They are not the same.
